# MySql with unistring removal

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I am learning MySql with python atm. I have get the server.py to pull the data from the mysql and print as well as post the data I need to the site. But I need to remove the format around it and just show the address with it I relize that its in a dictionary format with list in side. But could use a hand in pointing me in the rigtht direction for formating.

```
query = "SELECT email FROM email "                           
    email = mysql.query_db(query)                         
    return render_template('index.html', emaillist=email)
```

What I am getting

```
[{u'email': u'anna@gmail.om'}, {u'email': u''}, {u'email': u''},  }
```

Update found that i need to do it on he html side  this isnt working. Im still working on it any help would help

```
{{ email }}
<h1>These are all the Emails!</h1>

{% for email in email: %}
   <p>ID: {{ emaillist}}</p>
   <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
{% for k,v in emaillist.items() %}
    <p>Key: {{k}}</p>
    <p>Value: {{v}}</p>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {% for k,v in email.items() %}
    <p>Key: {{email}}</p>
    <p>Value: {{email}}</p>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}     the key is email and value is email  db name is email as well as column and no this doesnt work ty

Comment: No problem just trying to assist. What error are you getting?

Comment: UndefinedError: 'email' is undefined  throws that error on the page when i load that code

Comment: Ah it should be `emaillist.items()`... updated answer.